# Error message “Webpage not available” comes for a fraction of second before going away. not getting how to fix this?

Tags: android

I am trying to load a webpage into a webview in my android application and if the internet connection is down or the page is not able to load i am loading a custom html. The issue i am finding is that my custom html page is loading after fraction of second and the error "Webpage not available" is visible.

Is there any way to hide this completely. below is my onReceivedError

```
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCod,String description, String failingUrl) {
            webviewSuccess=false;
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        }
```

I also have onPageFinished() method and i understand why i am getting the issue. can someone help me out with this. Thank you